# GDK for Android Studio 3.0.1?

Tags: android-studio, google-gdk

I'm an Android newbie tasked with creating a simple app for Google Glass XE23.
I have downloaded & installed Android Studio 3.0.1, but find nothing in it related to Glass.
ALL search results are old and refer to much older versions of AS.  That includes anything I find at Google's Glass developer's site.
The AS Messages window contains:

> Gradle 'gdk-apidemo-sample' project refresh failed
>
> Error:failed to find target Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19 : C:\Users\Allan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

How/where do I get the GDK package?

Comment: All results I find for this refer to using Configure / SDK Manager, which apparently disappeared around AS version 2.3

Comment: I have respond to same question right now in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48943985/google-glass-sdk-gradle-sync-failed-cause-failed-to-find-target-google-inc-g/49191361#49191361

Answer (score 1):

In the `Android Sdk Manager` make sure to check `Show Package Details`. Then you see all package options and can install the GDK easily.

Android SDK Manager can be found at `Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was going to the apps build.gradle file and changing the compileSdkVersion to "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19". Android Studio should throw an error and prompt you to install the module using component installer.

Here's what that looks like:

```
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
```

You should get a prompt after trying to sync the gradle files again.