# Google Glass SDK: Gradle sync failed: Cause: failed to find target Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19

Tags: android, gradle, google-gdk, gradle-plugin

I am getting this error after importing and trying to build the gdk-apidemo-sample-master in Android Studio:

> Gradle sync failed: Cause: failed to find target Google Inc.:Glass
>   Development Kit Preview:19

Please advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and seems to be gradle doesn't support GDK in the newer versions. 
Open Android Studio and click open, under File menu, and select the directory of your project. In Top-Level *build.gradle* file, change the 8th line with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'` and the 20th line `runProGuard false` with `minifyEnabled false`. In *gradle-wrapper.properties* file change last part of the 6th line with `gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`. After that click on Try Again and it will work. If it ask you to update gradle version always ignore it, because if you update gradle it doesn't recognize the GDK. To start app in google glass also change the settings in Run menu, Edit Configurations. In Launch Options select nothing, beacause glassware doesn't have default activity.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step solution, that works for me on the newest Android Studio 3.1.2:

1. Close the Android Studio.
2. Change `classpath` in the `<your_main_project_directory>/build.gradle` to new one (currently
   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'` works good).
3. Start Android Studio and open your project again.

IDE will now correctly inform you about any other necessary updates. You can safely accept updating Gradle version, as it's working good now. At least in my project everything went flawlessly.

Examples of IDE prompts after above line change and opening the project:
[image]
[image]

Edit: As @Marcello Cuoghi said you might also need to select `Launch: Nothing` in the Run->Edit Configurations...->Launch Options.
Also in the `app/build.gradle` file change `runProguard false` to `minifyEnabled true` (usually not needed, but I had such once).